# Regex for ifconfig output

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to create a regex pattern to match the device name, ip address of the interface and the mac address.

I have these three matches:

```
device name = r'([^\s]+):\s'
mac address = r'ether (\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w)' 
ipv4 = r'inet\s+([^\s]+)'
```

this is the output of my ifconfig

```
eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 111.111.111.111  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 111.111.111.111
        ether 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 149694  bytes 162604639 (155.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 98703  bytes 13286845 (12.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 38  bytes 3424 (3.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38  bytes 3424 (3.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have tried using `.*?` in between but that hasn't worked. I know the loopback device doesn't have a mac, so was wondering if it is possible to do a NOT with the mac. Or just have two patterns and if it can't find all three use a second pattern to find the device name and ip address. If you could also provide a python 3 implementation that would be very helpful.

Comment: Show us your desired output, and the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the device name with

```
(.+?): flags
```

The IP addresses with

```
((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)
```

If you only want the *"inet"* entry, use

```
inet ((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)
```

And, the MAC addresses with

```
(?i)((?:[a-f\d]+:){5}[a-f\d]+)
```

Output

```
eno2
111.111.111.111
255.255.255.0
111.111.111.111
1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f
lo
127.0.0.1
255.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complex way of getting device name, private ip address and mac address of the current network interface.

Instead of this use the specific way to achieve your output...

For device name you can use this python script:-

```
import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()
```

For private ip address use this simple python script:-

```
import socket
import os

hostname = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
```

For getting mac address of the current network interface you can use this simple python script:-

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac

mac = get_mac()
```

I hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try split your text by `\n\n` into separate groups and then search individually for the information:

```py
import re

text = '''\
eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 111.111.111.111  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 111.111.111.111
        ether 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 149694  bytes 162604639 (155.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 98703  bytes 13286845 (12.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 38  bytes 3424 (3.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38  bytes 3424 (3.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0'''

pat_name = re.compile(r'^(\S+):', flags=re.M)
pat_mac = re.compile(r'^\s*ether (\S+)', flags=re.M)
pat_ipv4 = re.compile(r'^\s*inet\s*(\S+)', flags=re.M)

for group in text.split('\n\n'):
    name = pat_name.search(group)
    mac = pat_mac.search(group)
    ipv4 = pat_ipv4.search(group)

    name = name.group(1) if name else None
    mac = mac.group(1) if mac else None
    ipv4 = ipv4.group(1) if ipv4 else None

    print(f'{name=} {mac=} {ipv4=}')
```

Prints:

```
name='eno2' mac='1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f' ipv4='111.111.111.111'
name='lo' mac=None ipv4='127.0.0.1'
```